# Why it's always so hard to vertical align a element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

Please check my example. I just want to align the button with the input vertically. I have labels and they need to stay there. I just want to vertically align the button on the grey background.

```css
.tab-topbar {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    input {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12 tab-topbar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
    <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
    <input />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="text-right">
          <button>LOL</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't be really easy when your input is in a different column.

Answer (score 1):

use button addons

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">LOL</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `width` and `display:inline-block` to position these elements in the same line.

```css
.tab-topbar {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    input {
    width:88%;display:inline-block
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12 tab-topbar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
    <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
   
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
 <input />        
          <button style="width:10%;display:inline-block">LOL</button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using `display:flex` and move `input` box inside `text-right` class.

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.tab-topbar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-right {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12 tab-topbar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
      <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="text-right">
        <input />
        <button>LOL</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tab-topbar {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
input {
Width: 100%;
margin-right: 10px !important;
}
.flexedDiv {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12 tab-topbar">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
    <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 flexedDiv">
    
    <input />
<button>LOL</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Use this structure and flex in css, this would make your life easy

Comment: I like this answer. You saved my a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by using `Flexbox` and you need to update your structure. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.tab-topbar {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.formField {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="tab-topbar">
  <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
  <label>asasasfasgasgaaaga</label><br>
  <div class="formField">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm identity</button>
  </div>
</div>
```